# PHP substr not stripping file extension

Tags: php

Using the below php if I upload a .txt file named "example" the resulting uploaded file looks like

```
example.txt04-27-2020-1228
```

it is still has the extension .txt (which I want) but I am trying to get the file to read like this

```
example.04-27-2020-1228
```

Here is the code

```
<?php
    $uploaddir = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['name']);
    $withoutextension = substr($uploadfile, 0, strrpos($uploadfile, ".txt"));
    $fileD = $uploaddir . $withoutextension.date('m-d-Y-Hi').".txt";
   (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $fileD))
?>
```

Any takers? Cheers.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. If `$_FILES['name']` contains `example.txt`, then the result of your script in `$fileD` would be `example04-27-2020-1228.txt`, and not what you said.

Comment: you need a `dot` in front of the appended date?

Comment: @CBroe Thats what I would think, but its not, the resulting upload is "example.txt04-27-2020-1228" it is a text file ie. "example.txt04-27-2020-1228.txt" but I want it to be "example.04-27-2020-1228.txt"

Comment: This seems like it's asking for some debugging - just echo the variables after each step. I'm pretty sure the code you've posted is going to end up with `$fileD` having the upload directory duplicated, since you're prepending it to two different strings. Incidentally, if you want a filename without an extension, `pathinfo` can do that a lot more cleanly than string functions.

Comment: Then you must actually be doing something different than what you have shown us - https://3v4l.org/A1fVS shows what the code you have shown, does with the given input value of `example.txt`.

Comment: @CBroe Could it have something to do with move_uploaded_file or my PHP.ini?

Comment: Hard to imagine what that should be, because none of the available config settings should have much influence on how basic string operations work. (Multi-byte problems are likely not an issue here.) Have you _verified_ that `$_FILES['name']` actually contains what you think it should in the first place?

Comment: Thanks everyone, but @CBroe you pointed me in the right direction, changing '$_FILES['name']'  to '($_FILES['file']['name']' done the trick. I should have mentioned that "$_FILES" came from multipart/form-data